# Remove space under svg icon - where to add "display: block;" in svg code

Tags: svg

I have read a number of posts that answer how to remove the space under a .svg file. I have tried to use the  "display: block;" without any luck. I think it is because I am not sure where to place the code to make it work.

A link to my js fiddle is at the following: [where do I put display block in .svg doc][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/bethabernathy/gsarhk4c/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Beth

Comment: Space under where? Your fiddle just contains an SVG with some stray HTML tags after it.  If your SVG is posted in a page inside a `<div>` or something, then you should be showing that (or a simplified version of that).  Without the context we can't really tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi There, My row of icons are on this page:      http://patskailua.com/div6.html# The icon that I am having trouble with is located just above the text "Request a Brochure." This icon compared to the other 2 has a lot of white space underneath it. I am using a sprite to generate the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your `viewBox` is wrong.

If you want the circle to fill the area given to the SVG, then the `viewBox` has to match the dimensions of the circle.  Your circle has a width and height of 75, but your `viewBox` describes an area 135 wide and high.

To avoid this in the future when using Illustrator, you should either:

1. Scale your image so that it fills the artboard, or
2. [Uncheck the "Use artboards" option when saving as SVG.](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html)

The second problem (that `display:block` fixes) only becomes apparent when you have fixed the `viewBox` issue.

Have a look at the following example.  There are three versions of the SVG wrapped in a `<div>`:

1. Your original SVG. I have simplified the SVG to remove some of the icon unneeded for this demo. I have also removed the SVG boilerplate that is not needed when SVGs are being inlined.
2. The SVG with fixed `viewBox`.  Note the little gap at the bottom between the SVG and the bottom of the `<div>`.
3. Same as #2 but with `display: block` applied to the SVG.  Note the gap at the bottom is now gone.

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#example3 svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">

  <svg  viewBox="0 0 135 135">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:#398439;}
    </style>
    <circle class="st0" cx="37.5" cy="37.5" r="37.5"/>
  </svg>

</div>


<div id="example2">

  <svg  viewBox="0 0 75 75">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:#398439;}
    </style>
    <circle class="st0" cx="37.5" cy="37.5" r="37.5"/>
  </svg>

</div>


<div id="example3">

  <svg  viewBox="0 0 75 75">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:#398439;}
    </style>
    <circle class="st0" cx="37.5" cy="37.5" r="37.5"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: I did use the options mentioned in illustrator and changing the viewbox does work, but how do I make the icon back to its smaller size?

Comment: It will depend on how it is used in your page.  But you need to either give the `<svg>` a `width` and `height`. Or give its parent container a `width` and `height`.